# in next js 13 with app router, i want to get data from api

Tags: next.js

The website is working well, but when click on back button of browser it gives an error. Please see screenshots for more details

[problem when click on back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaoyX.png)
[this is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq8E1.png)

I want to navigate back without no error when click on the back button

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: remove await and async from getdistricts

Comment: function getDistricts(division) { return fetch('url${division}').then((res) => res.json())}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use() can be used to unwrap promises (similar to await), then **remove await and async from getDistricts** and use something like this :

```
function getDistricts(division) { return fetch('url${division}').then((res) => res.json())}
```

Let's check a quick example:

```
// app/page.jsx
import { use } from 'react';
import { ProductCard } from './product-card';

const Index = () => {
  const product = use(
    fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/1').then((res) => res.json())
  );

  return <ProductCard title={product.title} />;
};

export default Index;

// app/product-card.jsx
'use client';

export function ProductCard({title}) {
  return <div>{title}</div>
}
```

for more details you can read :

https://blixtdev.com/all-about-reacts-new-use-hook

Comment: The website is working well, but when click on back button of browser it gives this error.

Comment: @RakibulHasan first try what i suggested because the error is caused by the async and await used at getDistricts and called inside use() hook remove async and await and return from getDistricts the api call promise else use useEffect for the getDistricts